# Can a user click objects to generate code for charts and graphs in R

Tags: r

I am wondering if there is a way to click items in a data set or click items on the Menu, to create code that plots charts and graphs in R.  In Excel, the Macro Recorder does this pretty well, although it tends to spit out a lot more code than you actually need, but it is easy to go through the auto-generated code, clean it up, and in no time at all, you have what you need to create all kinds of visuals with VBA code.  Is there something similar in R?

I am reading a book about charts in R, and there are many great samples, with all kinds of code, but I don't see how it is easy to memorize all of this stuff!

Maybe there is some tool or package can be added in to do this work...  I'm just wondering...  Thanks.

Comment: In my experience, the limit of interaction has been Shiny apps, which can be written so that the users can choose variables from lists of parameters and their selections produce plots.  Check out the Shiny Gallery (https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/) for examples of this.

I realize that's not what you're asking for, but it's the closest I can come up with.  I haven't used the Excel Macro Recorder, but I have used the one for ImageJ, and in my experience that only works because of a set number of built-in tools or commands

Comment: Note that RShiny apps are built by writing code, so if you're looking for an easy way to _generate code_ that plots graphs and charts, Shiny apps is not what you're looking for.

Comment: You can certainly output plotting text/code with a Shiny Interface as the input.

Comment: @Vlo Sure, but you still need to write the code to create the Shiny app, so if OP's goal is to not write any code, then this wouldn't work.